# REMOTE_USER missing under ASP.NET after SSO

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm working on bringing an ASP.NET MVC application (IIS) behind a SSO system. I don't know much about the SSO but was told by the local support that after login by some CGI, the REMOTE_USER CGI/ServerVariable should be populated with the User's ID, which will be read by the ASP.NET application.

*The Problem*: Remote_User is always blank when called from an ASP.NET page (or from controller, etc.)

```
  <%: Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] %>
```

*What I've Tried*: Changing my web.config, authentication and authorization sections. The department mostly uses CF so I tried writing a quick ASP-Classic call **and it worked...**

```
 <% Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("Remote_User")) %>
```

I'm not familiar enough with CGI to guess at where the variables are lost, but if it's making it to an old .asp page the data must be being overwritten somewhere....

Comment: Why would you want to get the username this way instead of through Page.User.Identity.Name ?

Comment: As I mentioned, the login is handled by corporate single-sign-on (SSO) which populates the above Server Variables for all back-end applications. My application contains local identity information, but is only accessible from behind the SSO, which already knows the user's identity.

Comment: I think what @KeesdeWit was getting at was, try writing an httpModule to get the information from the headers. Your application can then use page.Identity.Name, without caring how it got. That's the point of the abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS settings, select your site, then in the **IIS** section, pick **Authentication**.

Disable **Anonymous Authentication**.

I have found that when I am trying to use Active Directory, allowing Anonymous Authentication means that all users are automatically anonymous.

I hope this applies to your SSO system too.